# how to add Select Box arrow in left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I unable to add the   arrow in select box i am using simply css code  and finding other  script but unable to  add the arrow in select box left side

[image]

Any help from any one greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the direction property in css of your select box. The direction property specifies the text direction/writing direction.

```
select { direction: rtl; }
```

It has a default value of ltr so change it to rtl. It will move your arrow to left.

Comment: but can you tell me how i can formatting my arrow with background color like image that i  posted with question.

Comment: use `background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat left #ddd`. Kindly accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work: text will be right aligned. `direction: rtl` is only to use for languages that read from right to left.

Answer (score 2):

To only move the arrow in the left side I have used only css:

```
select{
  direction: rtl;
}
select option{
  direction:ltr;
}
```

In this way the option still remain in ltr text.

Comment: This works w/out changing layout direction of any of the text, unlike the accepted answer.  +1.  Don't forget about `optgroup` also.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to go with Uniform JS. This will be quite simple to integrate with websites. You will get full flexibility to change the select box.

URL: http://uniformjs.com/

Only thing you need to do is, you need to change the background image as you wish. http://uniformjs.com/images/sprite-aristo.png

Comment: Links now point to some spammy site.